# ionicSideMenu: disable drag for one side but allow to other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app with 2 sidemenus, left and right:

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content >        
        <ion-nav-bar id="main_header">
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left" id="sidemenuleft">
        <ng-include src="'templates/menuleft.html'"></ng-include>
    </ion-side-menu>

    <ion-side-menu side="right" id="sidemenuright">
        <ng-include src="'templates/menuright.html'"></ng-include>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

in my controller, I can disable drag for them:

$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);

the question is: can I disable it for only one side? Example: drag to the left works, drag to the right, don't?

Answer (score 1):

For the records... I could do this with the following code (inside a controller):

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate._instances[0].left.setIsEnabled(true);
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate._instances[0].right.setIsEnabled(false);
});
```

Don't know if this is a goo approach, but it's working.

Comment: Did not work for me, $ionicSideMenuDelegate._instances seems to be empty.